# Gnome-shell thinks Thunderbird is still open

Tags: gnome, thunderbird

For some time when I exit Thunderbird the Gnome-shell does not seem to notice.

The dot next to Thunderbird's icon in the launch bar is indicating that the application is still running.

The annoying side effect is that trying to start Thunderbird again can not be done by simply clicking on the icon because (I assume) Gnome-shell focuses that "ghost" window instead.

I have to CTRL+click, then a second dot appears next to the icon.

Has anyone experienced the same problem (with Thunderbird or another app)?

Does anyone have a fix?

**edit**: using Ubuntu 21.04 et Thunderbird 78.13.0; I checked with `ps` that Thunderbird has indeed terminated.

Comment: It's likely that the `thunderbird` window has closed; but the processes haven't actually ended - why the dot remains, and a new process reports it is already running. How are you determining the closure has occurred on your *unstated* OS & release.

Comment: Mention specific version of your OS because it may matter. Also mention version of Thunderbird and how it is installed (default with the system? as a Snap? ...) When you have the issue, check with `ps ax | grep thunderbird` whether thunderbird is still running. Next to a line for your `grep` command, the presence of a second (or more) lines indicates running processed.

Comment: are you still using v 17.10? Please [edit] accordingly

Comment: It's a known bug that started with Ubuntu 21.04 and Thunderbird 78.11.0 (if memory serves me). It's not fixed in Thunderbird 78.13.0... as apparently they're saying it's a gnome-shell problem. The only short-term way to fix this is to log out, then log back in. Or use XORG instead of Wayland. Very irritating indeed.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to logging out and in as proposed by @heynnema, you can also run it again in terminal using `thunderbird` command but then you need to keep that terminal window open.

Comment: I am pretty sure I tried that one, but it didn't solve the problem. I cant' be sure, however, as the bug is gone with the latest Ubuntu update. 
Note however that you don't need to keep your terminal open, if you type `thunderbird & disown`.